# How to save output of a loop over a nested list

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I have a list of nested dataframes:

```
set.seed(1)
S1 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
S2 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,34,rep=TRUE)))
S3 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,21,rep=TRUE)))
S4 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,26,rep=TRUE)))
df_list1 = list(S1 = S1, S2 = S2, S3 = S3, S4 = S4)

set.seed(2)
S1 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
S2 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,34,rep=TRUE)))
S3 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,21,rep=TRUE)))
S4 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,26,rep=TRUE)))
df_list2 = list(S1 = S1, S2 = S2, S3 = S3, S4 = S4)

set.seed(3)
S1 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
S2 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,34,rep=TRUE)))
S3 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,21,rep=TRUE)))
S4 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,26,rep=TRUE)))
df_list3 = list(S1 = S1, S2 = S2, S3 = S3, S4 = S4)

set.seed(4)
S1 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,30,rep=TRUE)))
S2 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,34,rep=TRUE)))
S3 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,21,rep=TRUE)))
S4 = data.frame(replicate(2,sample(0:130,26,rep=TRUE)))
df_list4 = list(S1 = S1, S2 = S2, S3 = S3, S4 = S4)

df_list = list (df_list1, df_list2, df_list3, df_list4)
names(df_list) = c("AB_df", "BC_df", "DE_df", "FG_df")
```

I want to extract the first column of every dataframe by a loop and save this into a list. My problem is now how to make the loop to save it correctly. Which running index do I have to use? I tried different versions, but nothing worked. This is my code and I need to know now what to use instead of ???

```
datalist = list()
for (a in 1:length(df_list)) {
  for (b in 1:length(df_list[[1]])) {
    datalist[[?????]] = df_list[[a]][[b]][1]}}
```

To make it more clear: As output I want a list containing every 1st column of all 16 dataframes. So 16 list entries.

Comment: Please define the expected result more precisely. Do you want a list of size 4*4 = 16 containing all the first columns? Do you want it to have meaningful names reflecting from where each such column was taken?

Comment: Hi, yes! I want a list with 16 entries, 1 entry is the first column of every dataframe and it would be perfect to have a name where it is comming from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`purrr` works perfectly here.

```r
library(purrr)

datalist <-
  df_list %>% 
  # prepend top level names to dataframe names
  imap(~ set_names(.x, function(nms) {paste(.y, nms, sep = "-")})) %>% 
  flatten() %>% 
  map(1)
```

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be what I want. I dont understand the last part. What does map(1) do and how can I save this list into my gloval environment?

Comment: map(1) exctracts the first element (i.e. the first column) of each element (data.frame in our case) of the list it is applied to.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I wanted!